# When I render the smoke simulation, I get weird colors and skewing in some frames

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to render a nuclear explosion and it looks good in viewport. But when I render, some frames skews the smoke simulation, and sometimes it's just all orange.

I'm on 2.83.
Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060, Intel Xeon E5 2650 v3.

Here's some examples on how the frames look and the blend file. Frame 0133 is how it's supposed to look.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LUoLZ7tJmpXPBf-GAozhMXZquCEES8-9?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this with cycles or eevee?

Comment: Cycles. Eevee worked fine.